# Collapsibles não funcionam

Tags: html, html5, laravel, front-end, collapse

Estou usando um `framework` chamado `SBAdmin`, que não é nada mais que Bootstrap 4.
Porém ao criar o mesmo `collapsible` que o FW proporciona como exemplo ele não funciona em determinados casos, O erro está na url:

Quando é colocado uma URL assim: `localhost:8000/Cadastro` ele funciona normalmente. Já se eu colocar em uma URL assim: `localhost:8000/Cadastro/Aluno` já não funciona mais.

Estou usando o `BLADE` padrão do `laravel 5.4` por isso a uma ligação padrão entre o layout da página e o conteúdo em si, além disso o `collapsible` está sendo usado como menu no Layout padrão.

Comment: O framework está cendo chamado corretamente na página Cadastro/Aluno? O erro é só no collapsible? Poste seu código para ajudar

Comment: O Laravel ele usa o Blade como padrão que permite que uma pagina de conteúdo herde caracteristicas da pagina padrão, por isso se funcionou em um, funcionou em todos, mas este erro esta acontecendo em URL's de um caminho composto, por exemplo local/xxyy/pastalegal/
e nao em caminhos curtos como: local/xxyy/